# Parameter splatting with values read from a JSON config file

Tags: json, powershell, parameter-splatting

Using Splatting Hashtable for to set parameters and works well.
I am passing to a function as `New-ADUser @param`, the values that are set in splatting will be created in Active Directoy . However, my script will be running somewhere else. The Json file will be manipulated by the user.

How I can pass to this `New-ADUser @param` function the Json file instead Splatting table.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Convert the json to an object with `ConvertFrom-Json` an take the properties to create a splatting Hashtable

Answer (score 3):

Note: The following assumes that your JSON config file:

- contains an object whose *property names* match the *parameter names* of the target cmdlet, `New-ADUser`
- and that the property *values* are limited to strings, numbers, Booleans, and nested objects that PowerShell can *cast* to the parameter's type, based on the constraints explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54404461/45375).

These constraints ensure that a hashtable representation of that object can be used as-is for parameter [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting).

---

If you're running **[PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you can take advantage of [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json)'s
**`-AsHashtable` parameter**.

```sh
# Load JSON from file 'config.json' into a [hashtable] instance.
$params = Get-Content -Raw config.json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

# Use the hashtable for splatting.
New-ADUser @params
```

---

In **Windows PowerShell** (whose latest and final version is 5.1), you have to ***manually* convert the `[pscustomobject]` instance** returned by `ConvertFrom-Json` **to a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)**:

```sh
# Load JSON from file 'config.json' into a [pscustomobject] instance.
$paramsAux = Get-Content -Raw config.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Convert the [pscustomobject] to a [hashtable] instance by 
# making its properties (name-value pairs) hashtable entries.
$params = @{}
foreach ($prop in $paramsAux.psobject.Properties) {
  $params[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value
}

# Use the hashtable for splatting.
New-ADUser @params
```

---

The sample config JSON you've provided in a comment indicates that the prerequisites stated at the top are *not* met, and that ***custom transformation* of the config JSON is required in order to map onto the targeted [`New-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser) parameters:**

- *Update*: The truly intended target cmdlet turned out to be [`New-AzureADuser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0), for whose parameters the properties of the sample JSON below *are* a direct match, so no custom transformation is needed; hopefully, the technique shown is still useful to future readers who *do* need custom transformations.

```sh
# Create a sample JSON config file.
@'
{
  "GivenName": "Lili",
  "SurName": "Waters",
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "Lili Waters",
  "mailNickname": "LiliW",
  "userPrincipalName": "liliw@mailcom",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "xxyyzz"
  }
}
'@ > config.json

# Load JSON from file 'config.json' into a [pscustomobject] instance.
$paramsAux = Get-Content -Raw config.json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Convert the [pscustomobject] to a [hashtable] instance by 
# making its properties (name-value pairs) hashtable entries,
# applying custom transformations, as necessary.
$params = @{}
foreach ($prop in $paramsAux.psobject.Properties) {
  switch ($prop.Name) {
    # Map the JSON property names and values onto the appropriate 
    # New-ADUser parameters.
    'accountEnabled'  { $params['Enabled'] = $prop.Value }

    'mailNickname'    { $params['SamAccountName'] = $prop.Value  }

    'passwordProfile' { 
      $params['ChangePasswordAtLogon'] = $prop.Value.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn
      $params['AccountPassword'] = ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText $prop.Value.password
     }

    # All other properties directly map onto New-ADUser parameters.
    default           { $params[$prop.Name] = $prop.Value }
  }
}

# Use the hashtable for splatting.
# Note: To inspect the actual arguments being passed, use Write-Output in lieu
#       of New-ADUser, or just output the hashtable, $params, by itself.
New-ADUser @params
```

Note: I'm unsure as to what parameter the `mailNickname` property maps to; I've assumed `-SamAccountName` above; adjust as needed.

Comment: @AshlyneB: That's what the first two code snippets in the answer show, for PowerShell (Core) 7+ and Window PowerShell, respectively.

Comment: @AshlyneB: That's because the `PasswordProfile` property must be an _object_ with properties such as `forceChangePasswordNextSignIn`, not a _string_. The sample JSON you had provided earlier - which is now part of the answer - shows the requisite structure.

Comment: Also note that you cannot perform variable expansion such as `$PasswordProfile` _in JSON text_ - that value is used _as-is_, which is what you're seeing. You can assign an object _after_ having called `ConvertFrom-Json`, with `$param.PasswordProfile = $PasswordProfile`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @mklement0 is great and explains everything. i am stuck in the ps5 world currently, so i have to resort to skipping the -ashashtable option. I thought I'd show a little example of how I do it. This is just a more terse version of what @mklement0 has.

I currently use a oneliner for the conversion like the sql example below:

```
#get all my settings
$cfg = Get-Content settings.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

#convert the arguments i want to splat
$sqlargs = $cfg.sql.psobject.Properties|%{$h=@{}}{$h."$($_.Name)"=$_.Value}{$h}

#use args as splat
$dt = Invoke-Sqlcmd @sqlargs
```

and settings.json looks something like...

```
{
    "sql": {
        "QueryTimeout": 1800,
        "ConnectionString": "my connection string",
        "InputFile": "sqlfile.sql",
        "OutputAs": "DataTables"
    }
}
```

i have other settings in the file that do i don't need to pass as args, so i don't need to convert the entire file, just this one property for splatting.

i thought about creating a module for this since i use it a bit for various things, but i [this](https://github.com/torgro/HashData) project which looks like it would do the trick in that case.