# Is it possible to use with and endwith instructions?

Tags: powershell

I am translating vba code to PowerShell

Does `with` and `endwith` exist in PowerShell?

What is the alternative?

Could you give me an example?

Comment: No, it does not, but if you show us an example of a `With..EndWith` statement that you'd like to translate, we can probably show you relevant alternatives

Comment: i think you want the `using` keyword. this >>> about_Using - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting multiple properties at once - equivalent of VB's With statement to provide an implied object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378637/setting-multiple-properties-at-once-equivalent-of-vbs-with-statement-to-provi)

Answer (score 2):

The VBA `With ... End With` statement is just a shorthand syntax - see [With...End With Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement):

```
With objectExpression
    [ statements ]
End With
```

So, for example this VBA script:

```vb
With MyVar
    .PropertyX = 100
    .PropertyY = "myvalue"
    .MyMethod()
End With
```

is equivalent to this VBA script:

```
MyVar.Property = 100
MyVar.PropertyY = "myvalue"
Myvar.MyMethod()
```

which translates simply to this in PowerShell:

```bsh
$myVar.PropertyX = 100
$myVar.PropertyY = "myvalue"
$myvar.MyMethod()
```

However, if the `objectExpression` is a longer expression you can just assign it to a temporary variable:

```vb
With MyVar.MyProperty.MyOtherProperty
    .PropertyX = 100
    .PropertyY = "myvalue"
    .MyMethod()
End With
```

becomes this instead in VBA:

```vb
MyTempVar = MyVar.MyProperty.MyOtherProperty
MyTempVar.PropertyX = 100
MyTempVar.PropertyY = "myvalue"
MyTempVar.MyMethod()
```

which translates to PowerShell as follows:

```bsh
$myTempVar = $myVar.MyProperty.MyOtherProperty
$myTempVar.PropertyX = 100
$myTempVar.PropertyY = "myvalue"
$myTempVar.MyMethod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best alternative in Powershell:

```
foreach ($_ in $MyVar) {
    $_.PropertyX = 100
    $_.PropertyY = "myvalue"
    $_.MyMethod()
}
```

At least I like it...

Comment: Although this would work, using a foreach command implies you're iterating a list, which you're not. Quirky statements like this will leave others who review your code wondering. It would be cleaner to use $MyVar instead of all the $_ and remove the foreach statement altogether